# NSManagedObjectModel released after using valueForKey

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I am subclassing my `NSManagedObject` instances and setting up the `NSManagedObjectModel` and `NSManagedObjectContext` in the parent class.  When accessing data in a method that is in the parent my objectModel seems to released or otherwise reset when I use `[self valueForKey:@"id"]`.  Here is an example of what happens:

```
//this outputs NSManagedObjectModel
NSLog(@"model is %@",NSStringFromClass([model class]));

NSLog(@"this id is %@", [self valueForKey:@"id"]);

//this now outputs __NSCFString
NSLog(@"model is %@",NSStringFromClass([model class]));
```

Why would using valueForKey do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are using it, it will always loose the reference, because you are creating your objects dynamically, hence, your NSManagedObjectContext will always be released when you finish using your subclass.

You should put the reference for your NSManagedObjectContext inside a singleton or use a utility method like this to get the reference.

```c
#pragma mark - MOC
- (void)initMoc
{
    AppDelegate *delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    self.managedObjectContext = delegate.managedObjectContext;
}
```

Comment: You should not put your `NSManagedObjectContext` in a singleton.  That is a bad design choice.  The `NSManagedObjectContext` should be passed down into view controllers via dependency injection.  Also, the `AppDelegate` is not a singleton.

Comment: Once I moved these methods out of my model parent class and into another helper class I built everything started working fine, my objects don't loose reference anymore. I guess I was just trying to be too clever.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`id` is a reserved word.  What are you expecting the output to be in that line?  If you have defined a property called `id` and expecting that to be output you are going to run into a problem.

What does your parent look like? Your `NSManagedObjectContext` should be allocated somewhere else, usually in the `AppDelegate` if you are following Apple's templates.

How are you initializing these `NSManagedObject` instances?  If you are doing just `[[NSManagedObject alloc] init]` then that is also going to cause you an issue since that is not the designated initializer for `NSManagedObject`.

Comment: Can you point out the problems of calling my attributes "id". I did that sometimes and never had any problems, regarding it being a reserved word.

Comment: It is a reserved word.  When you call `-valueForKey:"id"` you can get back `self` instead of the value you think you are getting back. It might work today, probably won't work tomorrow, definitely won't work at some point in the future. You should have gotten a warning about using it and warnings in Objective-C are important.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, they definitely should throw a warning a least, but it never appeared.

Comment: I haven't gotten a warning either, and I get the result I expect back.  But if it is a reserved word I'll definitely rethink how I have my properties setup.